# Spotify not in launcher and shows as question mark in dock

Tags: gnome, software-installation, launcher, spotify, dock

I installed Spotify (v. 1.0.70.399.g5ffabd56-26) from the Ubuntu Software app (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

The app itself works fine, but isn't found by the launcher:

[image: Not in launcher]

I can start the app by typing `spotify` at the terminal, and it starts and runs fine but the icon in the dock is just a question mark:

[image: No icon in dock]

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Please remove and re-install it! Mine was just installed and the launch icon is present...

Comment: An uninstall-reinstall cycle didn't fix the problem. At least not by using "remove" in the software centre.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed spotify from the Ubuntu Software Center to replicate your issue, and in fact, when I open it, there is no icon, just a question mark as you can see in my 1st image.

[image]

To solve this issue I did the following:

Edit this file `~/.local/share/applications/spotify.desktop` with any Text Editor (e.g. gedit, nano, vim), I used gedit, so the command was:
`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/spotify.desktop`

Search for the line that says `Icon` and put the following text:
`Icon=/home/<yourUsername>/.cache/gnome-software/3.20/snap-icons/4e763d64d7d04a3b072fcb90e3798530916c6b8a-spotify-linux-256.png`

[image]

It is possible that in your system the name of the icon could be different, in that case just go to that folder and check for the name of the icon.

[image]

About searching the app, it works perfectly for me, try to uninstall and install again to see if it works.

Hope it helps, good luck and enjoy your music!

Comment: Thanks galoget. But the folder `~/.local/share/applications/` is empty for me! Is this maybe part of the problem?

Comment: Yes, it could be part of the problem, try creating that file in the empty folder, put the exact same content as shown in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Also noticed that if you install via Snap the icon path (sometimes) includes the version instead of "current" e.g.

1. My .desktop icon path is

   "Icon=/snap/spotify/**6**/usr/share/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-128.png"

   *however*
2. My Spotify Snap path is

   $ lp /snap/spotify/

   drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  146 Mar 24 18:32 **13**

   lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    2 Apr  4 16:54 current -> 13

One option is to swap the version for "current" in a .desktop file whenever you see this occur. Some other Snaps (GitKraken, Remmina) did the same thing at times.

Whenever you run across an issue like this, remember you can run "snap info " e.g. "snap info spotify" and get the contact information for the packager where you can check the issues list and create a new one if needed.

Spotify:
https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/bd-p/desktop_linux

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't even find the icon .png file.

This worked for me: I searched and downloaded the icon .png to computer. I followed galoget's intruction, and point the Icon= to the location of the downloaded icon file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue (Ubuntu 18.04) by creating a symlink:

```
# ln -s /snap/spotify/current/meta/gui/spotify.desktop /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop
```

This ensures my desktop file is up-to-date. This is assuming no customizations of desktop file are necessary.